# How to redownload shared apps under one's own apple id and decouple from someone else's?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-appstore, apple-id, family-sharing

Our minor child has his own Apple ID which is part of the family sharing household.  He also has an iPad on which he is signed into iCloud, iMessages, FaceTime, and the App Store with his own Apple ID.  Same for his iPhone.

When he went to update the apps today a bunch did update, but for a bunch of others he was prompted for a password to connect to the store (though it didn't say which Apple ID it wanted a password for).  He entered his own several times but was rejected.  It then occurred to me to have my wife enter *her* password and that took and the apps that weren't updating now updated.

While some of the apps on my kid's iPad that are apparently tied to my wife's Apple ID are things that cost money (and/or have associated in-app purchases), many of them (like Twitter, Discord, YouTube, Yelp, Keynote, GMail, Google Docs, Google Maps, etc.) are free.

We'd like our kid to be able to in the future update as many things as he can without needing my or my wife's password (especially when in not too many more years he's an adult and won't be part of Family Sharing anyways).

Is there any way to do this?  As a test for a couple of them (Twitter and Google Maps) we deleted them off the iPad and redownloaded them, but we still see them listed under my wife's purchases.

Is he just stuck?  Or is there some way to get these apps on his devices associated with his *own* Apple ID instead of my wife's?

His device history is as follows:

1. His first iPhone was my old 5S.  Most of the apps on that 5S were downloaded by my under my Apple ID directly, or were downloads by me via Family Sharing of things my wife had purchased under her Apple ID.  The phone was **not** wiped -- I just signed out of everything on it, deleted data and apps I wanted to delete and had my child sign into it.
2. The child's iPad was set up from the 5S using wireless migration (the 5S shows this moving dot code that was read with the new iPad's camera and that brought over all the settings, list of installed apps), though right from the start the child signed into it with his own Apple ID.
3. His current iPhone is my old 8.  However, this time I wiped the 8 first.  But post-wipe it was set up by using the iOS migration feature, using the iPad as the source.

So I'm guessing that a bunch of these apps (even free ones) not being under his own ID are because of the combination of Family Sharing and having the iPad and newer iPhone tracing their initialization to my old 5S which had things installed under my and me wife's IDs.

He hadn't updated the iPad or the 8 in quite a while and in fact they were both upgraded to 14.4 since the last time apps were updated.  I'm guessing (?) that iOS/iPadOS upgrade is why the prompt happened since he had been doing app updates before and hadn't gotten prompted for my wife's password in quite some time.

Comment: The apps are tied to the Apple ID that originally downloaded or paid for them.  Even if you get a different device because the apps are associated with the Apple ID and not the device.  The same thing should've happened on the iPad prior to the update to iPadOS 14.4 so I'm not sure why he wasn't prompted.

Comment: So until the end of time he's going to need my wife's password to update, say, Twitter on any of his devices now and in the future, unless he starts over with a brand new Apple ID that was never part of the Family Sharing?

Comment: I think the mistake was in 1. Since then each new device has inherited that. I cannot see a way out of it short of setting it up as a new device. Setting up with the same ID might allow those apps to be downloaded as part of family sharing rather than as the original owner. I'd be tempted to back it all up to iTunes [or however it works in Big Sur these days] rather than relying on OTA, so you can experiment.

Comment: I think @Tetsujin is correct is both the root of the problem and your next steps.

Comment: You make a lot of sense, @Tetsujin.  I think I may fool around with the 5S first (since no one's using it) -- wipe it completely, then have the kid sign into it with his own, existing ID and start downloading stuff and see what happens.